# Search excel column for value, record row where found in variable

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

```
     data = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1) # works

     data.filter[data['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip, regex=False)] # does not
```

With the above; I am simply trying to open my excel file into `pandas`, which is working fine. But then search a column, i.e. 'Member Address Line 3' to find a ZipCode that I define in my Zip variable. Once found I would like to get the row number of where it's found, and store that into a variable.

But currently, with the above, I am getting the below error:

```
    data.filter[data['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip, regex=False)]
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

____________ Just tried the below approach as well

```
            data.loc[data['Member Address Line 3']==Zip].index
```

Comment: Try `data.loc[data['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip, regex=False)]`

Comment: `data.filter(data['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip, regex=False))`, as the error message said: filter is a function, not a subscriptable object

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is simply

```
idx = data[data['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index
row_number = idx[0] if len(idx)>0 else None
```

or

```
row_number = data[data['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index.min()
```

which will return `nan` if `Zip` was not found.

([`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) filters the labels of the index, not the data in the dataframe)

Comment: Thanks, so your second option isn't reporting the row accurately. It prints a row number, but a inaccurate one. Not where value is found.

Comment: No, both options should yield the same result. Maybe you could share the output of `print(data['Member Address Line 3'])` (or at least the the first couple of rows until a zip code is encountered) so we have a reproducible example.

Comment: Here I try to better describe the context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255266/search-excel-columns-for-matching-text-value-print-row-s

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with input data (just the necessary amount) and the expected output. Thanks.