# Search excel columns for matching text value, print row #s

Tags: python, regex, excel, pandas, python-3.7

Here I grab the name and zip values from a different document; and store in variables: (works fine)

```
            Name = find_name.group(0)
```

**Then I simply want to search my excel file to find a match; where the `Name`  text value is found, get row number(s):**

```
            data = pd.read_excel(config.Excel2)

            row_number = data[data['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)].index.min()
            print(row_number)
```

The above outputs the incorrect row number when printed, I cannot understand why. *i.e.* It does not print the row where the matching text value is found within my excel document. It prints an erroneous row number, that doesn't match the `Name`.

**Then**, I have tried something like this; but this doesn't output anything at all: *(outputs Key Error)*

```
        idx = data[data['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)].index
        row_number = idx[0] if len(idx)>0 else None
        print(row_number)
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

My excel looks as follows (with about 11000 rows like the below, and 8 columns).

```
          A
1 |   Member Name     | Member Address Line 1 | Member Address Line 2
    RHONDA GILBERT       ADDRESS PT 1            ADDRESS PT 2 W/ ZIP
```

Comment: Could you please show the `data.head()` output? And could you give an example of the incorrect row number?

Comment: Just tested this and works for me with your code, can you print the output of `Name = find_name.group(0)`

Comment: So the use of 'Member Name' in both scenarios output a 'KeyError'. The use of other column names work, but output incorrect row number (ie. not where matching text was found)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have your excel file, so I setup the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
names = ["RHONDA GILBERT", "FRED FLINTSTONE", "FRED FLINTSTONE", "BARNEY RUBLE", "RHONDA GILBERT"]
add1 = ["123 Elm St", "254 Pine Ave", "254 Pine Ave", "654 Spruce Grove", "123 Elm St"]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names, add1)), 
   columns =['Member Name', 'Member Address Line 1']) 
df
```

It gives me the following output:

```
    Member Name     Member Address Line 1
0   RHONDA GILBERT  123 Elm St
1   FRED FLINTSTONE 254 Pine Ave
2   FRED FLINTSTONE 254 Pine Ave
3   BARNEY RUBLE    654 Spruce Grove
4   RHONDA GILBERT  123 Elm St
```

If I now search for "FRED" then I write it like so:

```
Name = "FRED"
matches = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)]
matches
```

and the output I get is this:

```
    Member Name     Member  Address Line 1
1   FRED FLINTSTONE 254 Pine Ave
2   FRED FLINTSTONE 254 Pine Ave
```

Note that if I ask for the indices of matches I get

```
matches.index
# outputs
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

These are the original indices of df. So then looking for the minimum value of the index

```
matches.index.min()
# outputs
1
```

This is the minimum of the indices. I am not too sure how your results deviated from the above. If you care to clarify, I will alter my explanation.